# how to remove N-th character from string in R?

Tags: r, stringr

Q1) Very simple. I have

```
a <- "* 3.45"
```

I need to remove the first and second character, so I have

```
b <- "3.45"
```

How do I do that?

Q2) A more generic question : 
How to remove all non-digit characters in front of digits in a character string?
So if I have `"%$aqs -3.45"`, I'll get `"-3.45"`?

Comment: The title of the question doesn't quite match the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to remove "non-digit character" in front of numbers, you can use some regular expressions

```
a <- "* 3.45"
b <- "%$aqs -3.45"
gsub("^[^0-9.-]+", "", a)
# [1] "3.45"
gsub("^[^0-9.-]+", "", b)
# [1] "-3.45"
```

here we remove anything at the start of a string that's not a digit, decimal point, or minus sign.

Answer (score 2):

For the first part, you can do:

```
substr(a, 3, nchar(a))

[1] "3.45"
```

Or:

```
substring(a, 3)
```